# YouTube style linking inside HTML5 Video player

Tags: video, javascript, youtube, html5, jquery

After a video has played on YouTube, often there will be a follow up link after the video has finished playing in the form of related videos.

I'm looking to implement similar into my HTML5 Video. It would look something like this:

[image]

At the moment, it seems there is nothing in the W3C spec for this (Links inside HTML5 video). Could anyone advise on a method of achieving? I have 50-100 videos on my site on which I would like to implement.

Currently I'm thinking a Javascript callback which initiates the Call to action buttons, though I have a feeling this could get complicated...